# Date formatting exception

Tags: java, date, format, date-formatting

i have the following date `2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00`

And this code :

```
    Long tt = null;
    String date = "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    try {
        Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(date);
        tt =  parsedDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        tt = (long) 9999999;
    }

    System.out.println(tt);
```

Output :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00"
>
> 9999999

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your input doesn't match your format. You've got microsecond precision in the input, and millisecond precision in the format.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your millisecond part has 6 digits not three, and the timezone is given not as an RFC 822 time zone but as an ISO 8601 time zone.

This will work:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX"
```

As was correctly pointed out in the comments, this will garble up the millisecond part if it ever deviates from `000000`.

Since Java 8 there is a much better way to parse dates and times. For ISO-8601 dates as yours, simply use this:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00")
```

Also see [Basil Bourque's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337935/6216216) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: S is for milliseconds, not microseconds. If the string was "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000999-00:00", your way of parsing would add 999 milliseconds instead of 999 microseconds (i.e. nothing, since a Date has a millisecond precision) to the date. So, basically, it only works if the microseconds part is always 000000.

Comment: As JB Nizet points out, this code *fails* if you do not always have zeros. Another example: "2017-02-19T12:23:37.123456-00:00" gives **incorrect result**  of `1487507140456`. See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/6px98W). The legacy date-time classes are limited to milliseconds resolution, and your suggested formatting pattern is behaving improperly. Use the java.time classes instead.

Comment: @JB Nizet and Basil Bourque: Thanks for the illuminating comments, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00" )
```

## Use java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### Milliseconds vs nanoseconds

The legacy classes support only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution, limited to three decimal places of fractional second. The java.time classes use [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution, for up to nine decimal places of fractional second. Your example data of six decimal places is for [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

### ISO 8601

Your input string happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Well, almost standard: Your example has a negative zero [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A negative zero offset is explicitly forbidden by the ISO 8601 standard. The standard requires a zero offset be marked with as a positive number with the `+` sign rather than `-` sign. However, [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) which claims to be a profile of ISO 8601 violates this rule with the unfortunate and unwise choice as a different connotation.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern at all.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Fortunately for you, the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class tolerates the negative zero offset when parsing your input.

```
String input = "2017-02-19T12:23:37.123456-00:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/I1seC1).

> odt.toString(): 2017-02-19T12:23:37.123456Z

Notice the use of ISO 8601 formatting by `OffsetDateTime::toString` when generating a string from our `OffsetDateTime`. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu`, and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your input date doesn't match the pattern you specified. Try changing the pattern:

```
    String date = "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000000-00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
```

For more information, you can look at documentation examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: S is for milliseconds, not microseconds. If the string was "2017-02-19T12:23:37.000999-00:00", your way of parsing would add 999 milliseconds instead of 999 microseconds (i.e. nothing, since a Date has a millisecond precision) to the date